# WPF and MVC4 Web API Internal Server Error 500 on POST

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So I'm attempting to attach to a web api method via a WPF service, but get only a 500 error on anything other than a GET.

WPF call:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var user = new MyUser
            {
                EntityID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FirstName = "WPF",
                LastName = "test"
            };
            var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<MyUser>(user, formatter);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:19527/api/");
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("MyUser", content);
                  //.ContinueWith((postTask) => result = (postTask.Result.Content == null) ? "Could not create user" : "User created successully!");
            var r = response.StatusCode;
        }'
```

...and the receiving controller:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string badgeId)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, (service.UserByBadge(badgeId) != null));
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(MyUser user)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, service.UpsertUser(user));
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyUser user)
    {
        if (service.UpsertUser(user)) return Request.CreateResponse<MyUser>(HttpStatusCode.OK, service.Get<MyUser>(u => u.BadgeID == user.BadgeID));
        return Request.CreateResponse<MyUser>(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, null);
    }'
```

The `service` on the WebApi controller is a GenericRepository, which is working fine, since the Get method returns as expected.  It's only when I use Post that I get the error.  Debugging the methods throws the break point in the Get, but not in the Post, so I don't think it's ever being called.

Here's the route config:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "{controller}", action = "{action}", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I've tried different examples from other SO posts, but none appear to address this issue specifically.  I'm guessing there's something wrong with how I've constructed the `Post()` method?

================================================================

RESOLUTION: Model being passed was failing property validations.  Why this was causing a 500, not certain.  But once I solved for this, API method began working.

If anybody has a "why" explanation, would love to know for future reference.

Comment: If you're using WebAPI, then you should be using a `MapHttpRoute` which usually does not include an action, e.g., `MapHttpRoute( routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Comment: Made that correction @Stephen but still 500 error.  

BTW, routes should include names: 'routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiDefault", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });'.  I like to use "Api" in those names to mitigate conflicts with other MVC projects in the solution.